# Issues regarding SIGNAL/SLOT qt4

Tags: c++, qt4

I have created a GUI which involves selection of topics from one ComboBox (*evaluation_box*) leading to load all the topics related to that particular topic into another ComboBox (*sequence_combo_box*).

The code used for SIGNAL/SLOT is as follows

```
  connect(ui_.evaluation_box, SIGNAL(currentIndexChanged(QString)), ui_.sequence_combo_box, SLOT(readSequenceFile(char *,char *,struct dirent *)));
```

But, on doing so I get the following error message:

```
Object::connect: No such slot QComboBox::readSequenceFile(char *,char *,struct dirent *)
Object::connect:  (sender name:   'evaluation_box')
Object::connect:  (receiver name: 'sequence_combo_box')
```

The header file includes the following:

```
#ifndef rqt_get_sequence_feeder__GetSequenceFeeder_H
#define rqt_get_sequence_feeder__GetSequenceFeeder_H

#include <rqt_gui_cpp/plugin.h>

#include <ui_get_sequence_feeder.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <image_transport/image_transport.h>    
#include <sensor_msgs/Image.h>    
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>    
#include <QImage>
#include <QList>
#include <QMutex>
#include <QString>
#include <QSize>
#include <QWidget>
#include <vector>

    namespace rqt_get_sequence_feeder {

    class GetSequenceFeeder
      : public rqt_gui_cpp::Plugin
     {

      Q_OBJECT
        public:
           GetSequenceFeeder();

        protected slots:            
          virtual void onFrameChanged(int);
          virtual void readSequenceFile(char *folder,char *sequence,struct dirent *select);
                                          .
                                          .
                                          .
       protected:    
         Ui::GetSequenceFeederWidget ui_;

     };
    }
```

And the `.cpp` is as follows:

```
using namespace std;
namespace rqt_get_sequence_feeder {

GetSequenceFeeder::GetSequenceFeeder()
  : rqt_gui_cpp::Plugin()
  , widget_(0)
{
  setObjectName("GetSequenceFeeder");
}


void GetSequenceFeeder::initPlugin(qt_gui_cpp::PluginContext& context)
{
    connect(ui_.evaluation_box, SIGNAL(currentIndexChanged(QString)),ui_.sequence_combo_box, SLOT(readSequenceFile(char *,char *,struct dirent *)));   
                                      .
                                      .
                                      .
}

void GetSequenceFeeder::readSequenceFile(char *folder ,char *sequenceFile,struct dirent *select)
{
                                     .
                                     .
                                     .
}
```

I have the function `readSequenceFile(char *folder,char *sequence,struct dirent *select);` declared in the header file as `protected slots:` I also tried declaring it as `public slot:`, did not work. I dont understand what am I doing wrong.

Comment: Do you have the body of the slot in the `.cpp` file?

Comment: Do you have the `Q_OBJECT` macro inside your class? It seems it's looking for `QComboBox::readSequenceFile`, not `YourClass::readSequenceFile`, which suggests the macro's missing. And unless all the parameters past the first one have default arguments, you won't be able to connect this anyway.

Comment: @Angew And with a `QMapper`? I've had to use one, so I'm asking this out of curiosity.

Comment: @AdriC.S. `QSignalMapper` just adds sender identification to zero-parameter signals. I don't think it could help here.

Comment: @Adri C.S: yes, I have the body in .cpp file

Comment: Nevermind, follow @Angew 's advice. :)

Comment: @Angew : Yes, `Q_OBJECT` macro is inside my class

Comment: @ADI And have you re-run MOC since adding the slot? Anyway, this is not really answerable without seeing more code, ideally an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Can you try removing the `struct` form `struct dirent` in both the declaration and the `connect()` call (it's superfluous in C++ anyway)? Maybe it's confusing Qt's text-based signal/slot matching.

Comment: I removed the `struct` from `struct dirent`. I still get the same error message.

Comment: Is `rqt_gui_cpp::Plugin` a QObject? Is `ui_.sequence_combo_box` really referencing this `GetSequenceFeeder` class? There's too much code missing where there could be a mistake to give a proper answer.

Comment: @JanickBernet: yes, `rqt_gui_cpp::Plugin` is a `QOBJECT` and also `ui_.sequence_combo_box` is referencing the class `GetSequenceFeeder` class

Answer (score 0):

According to your error message , your `ui_.sequence_combo_box` is a `QComboBox` , and obviously a `QComboBox` doesn't have a slot function named`readSequenceFile`.
`ui_.sequence_combo_box` should be a class inherit `QComboBox`

Comment: He could have extended the class and forgot the Q_OBJECT macro, in which case I think it would wrongly print the subclass name in the error message.

Comment: @JanickBernet: I have included the `Q_OBJECT` macro in the class. I don't understand what could be wrong